# -(void)dealloc and property(nonatomic, retain)

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have declared some two labels in .h file
and also declare

```
@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *label1; 
@property(nonatomic,retain)UILabel *label2;
```

how many time we have to release these label objects in dealloc. I am releasing only onece.

we have declare property so reference count will be increase and i am releasing once, where i release next. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advanced:

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you only release once in dealloc.. if you're using self.label1 = something multiple times it's good to do it like this:

```
    [label1 release];
    label1 = nil;
    self.label1 = X;
```

provided that you have made init of label before code above

Answer (score 3):

just once per ivar. i would write `dealloc` like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [label1 release], label1 = nil;
    [label2 release], label2 = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```